# Python, dynamically change the order of nested loops

Tags: python, for-loop

So i thought i might want to do this, but then realised that i don't need to, as it would not achieve anything. And at the moment, i can't think of a reason that you might need to, so it's more question of curiosity.

Is there a way to change the order in which a set of nested loops are performed?

for example;

Say i had something like:

```
for j in js:
  for k in ks:
    for l in ls:
      #do something
```

Is there a way that I could dynamically swap the `for j in ...` and `for k in ...` lines to change the order that things are done in the main loop body?

I should say, i realise i could do it with something like

```
variable_lists_list = [js, ks, lk]
for a in variable_lists_list[preference1]:
  for b in variable_lists_list[preference1]:
    for c in variable_lists_list[preference1]:
      #Do something
```

But is there a *neater* way, which would allow me to use `j,k,l` and not have to worry that there are not actually from the corresponding `js, ks, ls` lists?

The more i think about it, the more i think that if you're having to use a construct like this, you should probably rethink the problem, as it would just serve to confuse, but still, i press on. Is this possible?

The situation i was originally thinking of where it might be useful would be when breaking out of the loops would happen early due to something, perhaps if you were searching for something and had some knowledge that could help you decide which variables to loop over in preference. Other than something like that, is there some situation where a system like this would be useful?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `itertools.product` here.

Comment: @georg - I guess after this i could then sort the sets if `j,k,l` to preferably target various situations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I usually conditionally assign to the target of the loops. You could also use an associative array containing the assignments.

```
if SOMECONDITION1:
  target1 = js
  target2 = ks
  target3 = ls
elif SOMECONDITION2:
  target1 = ks
  target2 = ls
  target3 = js
elif SOMECONDITION3:
  target1 = ls
  target2 = js
  target3 = ks

for j in js:
  for k in ks:
    for l in ls:
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's example how to simplify that using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

a = [1,2,3]
b = 'abc'
c = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

if <some condition>:
    lists = a, b, c
else:
    lists = c, a, b

for x,y,z in product(*lists):
    print x,y,z
```

Comment: This is not what i meant about using `products`, as now there needs to be some logic inside of the loop to determine whether `x,y,z` are part of `a, b,` or `c`. I meant something like `for j,k,l in sorted(product(js,ks,ls), key=someFunction):` - where `someFunction` would sort them depending on the circumstances.